# Using headless chrome displays empty part of the page

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

When using chromedriver in a protractor script, to test an angular page, I obtain different results using "Headless" or "Normal" browser.

Actually, if I use a "repeater" locator, to display the items in the "empty" list, it returns that there are 5 items, but the "headless" chrome driver fails to render them. Look at the screenshots.

I'm using ChromeDriver 2.45, which supports Chrome Version 70 to 72, I have version 71.
My OS is Windows 10.
Protractor version 5.1.1
Angularjs version 1.5

Here's the configuration file:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    rootElement: 'html',
    chromeDriver: 'C:\\srv\\build\\applications\\chromedriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe',
    getPageTimeout: 60000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
            chromeOptions:{
              args:["--headless"]
            }
    },

specs: [ 'features/*.feature' ],
baseUrl: '',
cucumberOpts: {
    tags: '',
    require: [ 'steps/*.spec.js' ],
    monochrome: true,
    strict: true,
    plugin: "json"
 },
};
```

[image: Regular Chrome rendering all items in the list]

---

[image: Headless Chrome fails to render the list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to problem is in the window size. By default, headless mode is not a fullscreen, so some elements are automatically moved and hidden (as when you try manually to resize the window)

Just add to your conf:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you update args to

```
capabilities: {
    ...,
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800x600"]
    }
}
```

For the exact configuration mentioned i am able to automate headless with no issues.

Reference https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#using-headless-chrome